What does probability sensitivity mean in this context?
I read this paper which used copula in order to construct the conditional distributions of runoff for given values of each of the studied climatic factors such as precipitation and air temperature. For example, the following plots show the conditional distributions of runoff corresponding to low, medium and high precipitation ($25$th percentile, $50$th percentile, $75$th percentile, respectively).

The authors go on to define probability sensitivity indices. They defined "total probability sensitivity" as,
$$TPS= \int F(v|u_i)-F(v|u_j)dv$$
Where $u$ is climatic factor and $v$ is runoff.
However, I believe they meant a definite integral as they expressed $TPS$ by number later in the results section. The index is basically the area between two (here consecutive) graphs of conditional distribution. For example in the above plot one can visually see that, $$\text{TPS}_{\large\text{P25th}\rightarrow \text{P50th}} < \text{TPS}_{\large \text{P50th}\rightarrow \text{P75th}} $$
Unfortunately, I didn't grasp the concept of "probability sensitivity" in this context. Does that mean probability of runoff occurrence is more sensitive to changes in  precipitation from medium to high value than changes in precipitation from low to high value? Even with this assumption, I still cannot make sense out of it. Also, I'm interested to see if the concept of probability sensitivity is defined this way in other contexts (I couldn't find any).

Perhaps you can say $$\mathbb E[V \mid U=u_i] = \int\limits_0^\infty \big(1- F(v \mid u_i)\big)\, dv$$ at least if $V$ is always non negative and the integral is finite, and so $$\int\limits_0^\infty \big(F(v\mid u_i)-F(v\mid u_j)\big)\,dv = \mathbb E[V \mid U=u_j]  - \mathbb E[V \mid U=u_i]$$ measures the sensitivity of the conditional expectation of the runoff to changes in the climatic factor.

Yes, that works too (though I would have guessed "runoff" seems likely to be non-negative)
